# Determine scroll direction on a page that fits inside the window

Tags: javascript, scroll

I want to implement a scroll down menu on my website.

On pages that are taller than the browser window height, I can test the scroll position with `window.pageYOffset` to decide if the menu should scroll down or not.

However, on pages that are shorter than the browser height, I cannot use the same method, since `window.pageYOffset` is always `0`. Instead, I need to detect the direction of scroll. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of:

`window.pageYOffset` and `window.innerHeight`

You will be able to calculate how much of your menu is in view and which way to scroll.

Comment: How so?? The menu is hidden initially. It drops down only when scrolling has reached the top of the page.